# Ограничить время ожидания наличия ssh-соединения

Tags: python, python-3.x, ssh, timeout, paramiko

Есть несколько сетевых устройств. Соединение устанавливается с каждым из них поочередно. Когда есть соединение, должна появляться табличка - ок, когда нет - no. Проблема в том, когда с одним устройством нет соединения, истекает время ожидания, и до появления окошка с "no" программа просто не доходит. Как можно ограничить в коде время ожидания ответа от устройства, оборвать установление соединения? Например, если прошло 5сек и нет ответа, выводить окошко такое-то. Код приведен ниже. Использую python3 и paramiko, Windows7.

```
ssh = SSHConfig()
params = ssh.lookup(user_password_rnm)
ssh = SSHClient()
ssh.set_missing_host_key_policy(AutoAddPolicy())
ssh.connect(ipAddress_rnm, port=22, username=user_name_rnm,
            password=user_password_rnm)
if ssh.invoke_shell():
    st = ['with: ', name_rnm, ' - OK']
    showinfo('Connection', ' '.join(st))
    ssh.close()
else:
    st = ['with: ', name_rnm, ' - NO CONNECT']
    showinfo('Connection', ' '.join(st))
```

в if возникает ошибка "время ожидания истекло" и до else выполнение программы не доходит. Как сделать, чтобы появлялось окошко NO CONNECT?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Беглый просмотр документации показал, что при неудачном соединении `invoke_shell` выбрасывает исключение, а вы его нигде не обрабатываете. Вам надо обернуть `invoke_shell` в `try … except` (да и `connect` по-хорошему тоже).

```
try:
    ssh.connect(ipAddress_rnm, port=22, username=user_name_rnm, password=user_password_rnm)
    ssh.invoke_shell()
    st = 'with: {0} - OK'.format(name_rnm)
    showinfo('Connection', st)
    ssh.close()
except (BadHostKeyException, AuthenticationException, SSHException) as e:
    st = 'with: {0} - NO CONNECT. Reason: {1}'.format(name_rnm, str(e))
    showinfo('Connection', st)
```

Comment: Спасибо, изменил строку таким образом: except TimeoutError as e: и заработало как надо. Еще раз спасибо.